# GetListItemChangesSinceToken Folder Query option

Tags: list, query, spquery

I would like to get the list of folders and list items one level at a time, instead of querying all items under a SharePoint list.  I plowed through SharePoint documentations and Stackoverflow and such to make sure I am using the `<folder>` options proper, but still the `GetListItemChangesSinceToken` still returns *everything* under the SharePoint list.

The site structure is:

- http://mysitecollection/mysite/DocLib
- DocLib has documents and folder structure under it.
- tried on 2010 and 2013 server with similar result

The call:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/"><soap:Body>
<GetListItemChangesSinceToken>
<listName>doclib</listName>
<queryOptions><QueryOptions>
<Folder>/mysite/doclib</Folder>
</QueryOptions></queryOptions>
</GetListItemChangesSinceToken></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Our servers are of 2010 and 2013.

Question:

- is there anything wrong with my call?  I pared down the call to minimum, and also I tried various input e.g. trimming the '/' front and back, using a subfolder instead, etc. etc. but no different
- or, is it actually supposed to be working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GetListItemChangesSinceToken requires `changeToken` that you're not passing, if you do not pass it, you will get all items.

"By including this token when you call GetListItemChangesSinceToken, the server looks for only those changes that have occurred since the token was generated. Sending a GetListItemChangesSinceToken request without including a token returns the list schema, the full list contents and a token."

[Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc264031%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Comment: That is in fact the case!  GetListItemChangesSinceToken appears to behave very similarly as GetListItems when no token is passed, but not in all cases.  In my case, when <Folder> option is used, I would not have a token.  I switched to use GetListItems and now it works.